# How can one use git-flow effectively on a project in which more than one major version is being maintained?

Tags: git, workflows, gitflow

I've migrated several of my projects over to the [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) work flow, and I'm loving it.  However, I haven't found a best practice that keeps things flowing as smoothly when working with a project in which more than one major version is maintained at a time.

*Specifically, I'm not maintaining a "free version" and a "paid version" or any other parallel model, I'm talking about a project in which Version 1 gets released, and remains supported with minor versions (1.1, 1.2, etc.) until Version 3 has been released, at which point 2 and 3 would be maintained, until 4 is released...you get the idea.*

How have you, or would you, maintain two or more supported versions of a project at once in a gitflow workflow?

Comment: Don't have any examples atm, but projects I know of used separate repositories for different major versions, and backport patches from one to the other.

Comment: @ProdigySim: Thanks for the data point, but is it just me or would that add a certain amount of overhead to track and manage?

Comment: @ProdigySim I suspect that those projects didn't use a tool with the branching and merging capabilities of git.

Comment: @Rein They use Mercurial. I don't think branching would be very clean in terms of tracking parallel major-versions of software.

Comment: Then my suspicion was correct. And yes, it is quite clean if your tool supports it properly. git and the Linux kernel both do it this way.

Comment: related (possibly duplicate) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579056/multiple-development-branches-with-git-flow

Answer (score 10):

`man gitworkflows`, the grand daddy of the 'git flow' workflow, describes general git workflow guidelines; the use of `pu`, `next`, `master` and `maint` branches; and how `maint` is managed. If you have multiple maintenance branches, you can name them, for instance, `maint/1.x`, `maint/2.x` and so forth.

The key is not so much how to use the git commands, but how to build a reasonable process. Decide what things are important to you (ease of backporting?) and build (and document) a workflow that satisfies those constraints.

Comment: But does this answer the question? Namely, does git-flow support a flexible release model as described in the question, or does one revert back to basic git commands? ("gitworkflows" describes basic git workflow usage, pre-git-flow.) Git-flow was created (ostensibly) to simplify git merge/branch processes, so teams (with varying degrees of git-fu prowess) could focus on coding and avoid time-consuming "mis-mergerment" mistakes. Is it possible w/ git-flow to maintain and develop v1.2.{1,2,3,..} at the same time as v2.5.{1,2,3,...}? Perhaps w/ long-term release branches? Or master1, master2,...?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would duplicate the `master`, `release`, and `develop` branches for every major version you are maintaining.  How they interact with each other remains the same.  For `feature` branches, just make sure to branch *from* the oldest branch you intend to merge back *into*, which prevents pulling in unwanted dependencies.  Then when you merge your `feature` branch back in, you just do additional merges into each appropriate newer major version branch.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of master to include *every* released version?

Comment: @HedgeMage, in a more linear release cycle that's the case, but that's highly impractical for parallel major versions.

Comment: This seems like the most practical solution, unless there is some tried-and-true trick using hotfixes or such that i'm not aware of. I've been searching for a way to introduce git-flow and still be able to (as an unfortunate prerequisite) keep our existing release model, where we have to maintain/develop older releases (not just hotfixes). So v5.1.x will stick around (w/ new features added, bugs fixed, etc) a couple years after v6.1.x is released. About 2-3 major versions supported and developed at any given time. But bug fixes need to be applied to each version where the bug exists.